# How do I substract a substring from a JSON string using a regular expression?

Tags: regex, perl, twitter, twitter-feed

So I found these links which are related for the task. First
[using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707563/find-associated-value-to-a-keyword-in-file-with-python),  second [using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454414/how-can-i-find-a-string-after-a-specific-string-character-using-regex), third [using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874915/perl-extracting-data-from-text-using-regex)

Now I'm too new with Perl and what I want to do is work with some json streams from twitter.
What I'm looking at is this:

```
..E","location":"Hollywood, Los Angeles, CA ","screen_name":"i..
```

How do I find *"location":* using regex and then assign a variable to contain *Hollywood, Los Angeles, CA*?

```
sub get_location {
# pseudo code:  
# look for "location":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
# assign $tmp_loc = Hollywood, Los Angeles, CA (in this case)
# return $tmp_loc; }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perl has [libraries for dealing with JSON](http://search.cpan.org/dist/JSON/). Why not use one of those?

Alternatively, as you're dealing with Twitter, why not use [Net::Twitter](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Twitter/) which makes Twitter API calls and returns the results to you as Perl data structures.

These days, a lot of Perl programming is a matter of knowing which [CPAN modules](http://search.cpan.org/) to string together. If you're not using CPAN, then you're missing out on a lot of the power of Perl.

Answer (score 3):

[Perl JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON).

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't use regular expressions anywhere you need to find something in a string... They have their purpose, but not here.

If you have a JSON encoded string just decode it. I have no experience with Perl but I see that others recommend using a module from [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=JSON&mode=all).

Answer (score 0):

First you need a regex that matches the text you want to capture.  Since you only put a snippet I will only put a snippet of it also.

```
$text = ' ..E","location":"Hollywood, Los Angeles, CA ","screen_name":"i..';
if( $text =~ /.*location":"(.[^"]+)",.*/ ) {
  $tmp_loc = $1;
}
return $tmp_loc;
```

Comment: The recommendation by others to use the CPAN module is the right answer, at least to the question we all think *should* have been asked.  That said, the text above is the precise answer to the question and is very handy to have.  Both answers are valuable.

Comment: Yes I agree, thank you krico and the others who took their time answering.